# How to improve webscraping speed using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have made a python script for webscraping product information from Target using Selenium. Since there are a lot of products I have added a loop to iterate the process. Unfortunately this process is too slow and I was wondering if there were ways to improve the efficiency i.e use wait times etc.

For each iteration the information of the products is appended to a list 'lstTitles'. Below I have attached part of the code:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless=new')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
# loop on excel dataset
lstReview = []
name='Target' #for now
x_lst=[]
for i in files:
    dpci = i
    print(dpci)
    # variables
    lstTitles = []
    OverallRating = ""

    # navigate to the target page
    driver.get('https://www.target.com/s?searchTerm=' + dpci)
    time.sleep(5)
    glink=driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value='//*[@id="pageBodyContainer"]/div[1]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/div/section/div/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/a');
    print(type(glink))
    # first link open
    flag=0
    for i in glink:
        print(i.get_attribute('href'))
        i.click()
        flag=1
        break
    if(flag==0):
        continue #if link not found then go to next dpci


    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1000)")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1000, 2000)")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(3000, 4000)")
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(4000, 5000)")
    #input("TEST")
    loadMoreFound = "Yes"
    #dtlink = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR('.h-text-center.h-padding-v-tight')[0])
    # Click on Load More Button
    while loadMoreFound == "Yes":
        loadMoreFound = "No"
        try:
            print("load more button")
            clink=driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value='.h-text-center .h-padding-v-tight')
            #print(len(clink))
            #print(type(clink))
            #print(clink)

            for loadmore in clink:
#                 print("in the for")
                t = loadmore.get_attribute('innerHTML')
#                 print(t)
                #input("load more")
                if "Load" in t:
#                     print("Load more button found")
                    loadMoreFound = "Yes"
                    loadmore.click()
                    time.sleep(3)
                    break
        except:
            print("Error1")
            loadMoreFound = "No"
    counter = 0
    
    # Title
    time.sleep(3)
    ReviewTitle=driver.find_elements(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value='jfrTHg')
    #print(str(len(ReviewTitle)))
    # Get Reviews
    for i in ReviewTitle:
        t = i.get_attribute('innerText')
        #print(t)
        lstTitles.append(t)
        #input("get")
    print("Moving to next DPCI")
```

I have added `time.sleep` wherever a new element was to be located or clicked. Apart from that my intuition behind wait times is not very solid so I am not sure whether to add an explicit wait or implicit wait to my code. Any feedback would highly appreciated!

Comment: The core issue here is that you're using `selenium` for scraping. It's not a web scraper. In a scraping setting you should really use it to interact with elements on the page to get to relevant pages, but then scraping should be done using a dedicated scraper, like `scrapy`

Comment: And of course you have too many unnecessary `sleep` instructions. There's no reason to sleep between `scrollTo` commands. If you want to avoid getting blocked by anti-scraping systems you should just use a single sleep between loading web pages.

Answer (score 2):

1. time.sleep() is not the best way to handle waiting in Selenium. Instead, use Selenium's built-in WebDriverWait class

Example:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

# Wait up to 10 seconds before throwing a TimeoutException unless the element is found
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'element_id')))
```

2. When you know there's only one of a certain element on the page, use find_element_by_... instead of find_elements_by_... (e.g., when getting 'glink'). This is slightly more efficient because Selenium stops looking as soon as it finds the first match.
3. Your current scrolling pattern involves fixed distances and wait
   times. Instead, try scrolling until a certain element is found or
   until you can't scroll any further.
4. Instead of continuously checking for the 'Load more' button, you can
   set up a loop that stops when the button isn't found or can't be
   clicked.
5. If you're scraping multiple pages independently,
   you can make use of multiprocessing in Python to scrape multiple
   pages at the same time.